# Random forest/Maxent environmental predictor layers using vector data, in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector-layer, random-forest, maxent

I am attempting to use a vector layer as a predictor environmental layer for use in classification/predictor models (eg Random Forest/Maxent). I have attempted to include a bathymetric substrate layer, specifically 'High energy infralittoral rock' by doing a vector to raster transformation (following GEE doco). I have created a band, but it is not working properly, and can't be joined to the other enviro layers without crashing the classification. Any ideas on where i am going wrong?

```
//Import data
//-- Area Of Interest Polygon
var aoi_polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[142.8169776552576,-38.660150171229965], 
[143.0586768740076,-38.660150171229965],
[143.0586768740076,-38.57323675496147],
[142.8169776552576,-38.57323675496147],
[142.8169776552576,-38.660150171229965]]);

// --Specify location
var geo = ee.Geometry.Point([142.99126680969238,-38.62060224055215])
Map.setCenter(142.99126680969238,-38.62060224055215, 12); //Centre of Area of Interest
var opacity  = 0.5;

//--Coastal waters shapefile
var vic_waters = ee.FeatureCollection('users/s3825806/Vic_Waters')

// Compute the intersection between vic_waters and area of interest
var vic_waters_aoi = aoi_polygon.intersection(vic_waters, ee.ErrorMargin(1));

//--Environmental layers
// ---Substrate

var Sub_1 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/s3825806/Substrate_vic_waters')
.filterBounds(vic_waters_aoi);

//filter to column/variable of interest
var Substrate_1 = Sub_1.filter(ee.Filter.eq('HAB3BIOTTL', 'High energy infralittoral rock'));
print(Substrate_1, 'HEIR')
//Map.addLayer(Substrate_1,{color:'yellow'}, 'Substrate1', 0);

// Make an image out of the HEIR attribute as requires an integer??
var HEIR = Substrate_1.map(function(feature){
  return feature.set('HighEnergyInfralittoralRock', 1);
});
print(HEIR, 'HEIR')
//Map.addLayer(HEIR,{color:'yellow'}, 'HEIR', 0);

///Vector to raster transformation?
var SubstrateImg = HEIR
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['High energy infralittoral rock']))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['High energy infralittoral rock'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});
print(SubstrateImg, 'SubstrateImg')
Map.addLayer(SubstrateImg,{color:'yellow'}, 'Img', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no property named `'High energy infralittoral rock'` in the `HEIR` object. Thus, you need to indicate a valid name when filtering the collection, as well, as to convert the vector into an image. I am asumming that the property you are interested in, is the one you added to the Feature Collection: `'HighEnergyInfralittoralRock'`.

```
var SubstrateImg = HEIR
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['HighEnergyInfralittoralRock']))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['HighEnergyInfralittoralRock'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonathon. Yes I am trying to add a band to my environmental predictor layer with just the high energy infralittoral rock in it, since this is a predictor of where a macroalgae grows. I have fixed the error and added to the answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jonathon I figured out the issue. I just needed to change a variable name in the last section and it works. Adding the working code here so it can help someone else in future, hopefully.

```
//Import data
//-- Area Of Interest Polygon
var aoi_polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[142.8169776552576,-38.660150171229965], 
[143.0586768740076,-38.660150171229965],
[143.0586768740076,-38.57323675496147],
[142.8169776552576,-38.57323675496147],
[142.8169776552576,-38.660150171229965]]);

// --Specify location
var geo = ee.Geometry.Point([142.99126680969238,-38.62060224055215])
Map.setCenter(142.99126680969238,-38.62060224055215, 12); //Centre of Area of Interest
var opacity  = 0.5;

//--Coastal waters shapefile
var vic_waters = ee.FeatureCollection('users/s3825806/Vic_Waters')

// Compute the intersection between vic_waters and area of interest
var vic_waters_aoi = aoi_polygon.intersection(vic_waters, ee.ErrorMargin(1));

//--Environmental layers
// ---Substrate

var Sub_1 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/s3825806/Substrate_vic_waters')
.filterBounds(vic_waters_aoi);

//filter to column/variable of interest
var Substrate_1 = Sub_1.filter(ee.Filter.eq('HAB3BIOTTL', 'High energy infralittoral rock'));
print(Substrate_1, 'HEIR')
//Map.addLayer(Substrate_1,{color:'yellow'}, 'Substrate1', 0);

// Make an image out of the land area attribute as requires an integer??
var HEIR = Substrate_1.map(function(feature){
  return feature.set('HAB3BIOTTL', 1);
});
print(HEIR, 'HEIR')
//Map.addLayer(HEIR,{color:'yellow'}, 'HEIR', 0);

///Vector to raster transformation?
var SubstrateImg = HEIR
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['HAB3BIOTTL']))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['HAB3BIOTTL'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});
print(SubstrateImg, 'SubstrateImg')
Map.addLayer(SubstrateImg, {
  min: 3e8,
  max: 1.5e10,
  palette: ['FCFDBF', 'FDAE78', 'EE605E', 'B63679', '711F81', '2C105C'] 
}, 'SubstrateImg', false);
```